# Weird output with WriteConsoleOutputA

Tags: c++, winapi, memory, console, stdvector

I'm trying to print color pattern in Win32 console by using `WriteConsoleOutputA()` and `std::vector<CHAR_INFO>`; every thing seems OK. But when I tried to use 2 dimensional vectors `std::vector<std::vector<CHAR_INFO>>` the `WrtieConsoleOutputA()` grab some memory junks in output. I don't know where is the bug in my code.

Here's my code:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    const int width = 80, height = 25;
    COORD charBufferSize{ width, height };
    COORD characterPosition{ 0, 0 };
    SMALL_RECT writeArea{ 0, 0, width - 1, height - 1 };
    std::vector<std::vector<CHAR_INFO>> backBuffer(height, std::vector<CHAR_INFO>(width));

    for (auto& i : backBuffer)
    {
        for (auto& j : i)
        {
            j.Char.AsciiChar = (unsigned char)219;
            j.Attributes = rand() % 256;
        }
    }

    WriteConsoleOutputA(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), backBuffer[0].data(), charBufferSize, characterPosition, &writeArea);
}
```

Comment: Unlike a two-dimensional array, a two-dimensional vector's memory is not guaranteed to be contiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the memory allocation layout of *nested* `std::vector`s, and its mismatch with what the Win32 API `WriteConsoleOutput()` expects.

`std::vector` allocates its memory *contiguously*. But if you have a `std::vector` *nested inside* an outer `std::vector`, the *whole* allocated memory is *not* contiguous anymore!

If you want a whole contiguous memory block, you should allocate a *single* `std::vector`, having total size `width x height`, and use that as the memory buffer for `WriteConsoleOutput()`.

I slightly modified your code following this path, and it now seems to work:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    const int width = 80;
    const int height = 25;
    COORD charBufferSize{ width, height };
    COORD characterPosition{ 0, 0 };
    SMALL_RECT writeArea{ 0, 0, width - 1, height - 1 };

    //
    // NOTE:
    //
    // Wrong memory layout: vector<vector<...>> is *not* contiguous as a whole
    //
    //  std::vector<std::vector<CHAR_INFO>> backBuffer(height,
    //                                                 std::vector<CHAR_INFO>(width));
    //

    //
    // Correct memory layout: allocate a single *contiguous* block
    // of memory, to store a 2D array of width x height
    //
    std::vector<CHAR_INFO> backBuffer(width * height);

    //
    // Iterate through the backBuffer items
    // as if it were a 2D array of size width x height
    //
    for (size_t row = 0; row < height; ++row)
    {
        for (size_t col = 0; col < width; ++col)
        {
            CHAR_INFO& curr = backBuffer[row*width + col];

            // Your previous code
            curr.Char.AsciiChar = static_cast<unsigned char>(219);
            curr.Attributes = rand() % 256;
        }
    }

    WriteConsoleOutputA(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 
                        backBuffer.data(), 
                        charBufferSize, 
                        characterPosition, 
                        &writeArea);
}
```